# How do I filter the top 1% and lower 1% of data in each group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a data set that includes PRICE, SUBTYPE, and others. I want to do some outlier removal before I use the dataset. I want to remove rows for things where the price is ridiculously high or low, in each SUBTYPE.

For each SUBTYPE look at the range of the PRICEs and remove or filter out rows.
Keep rows that fall between:   PRICErange * .01   |KEEP|   PRICErange * .99

This was provided to me by a Martin Smith on stackoverflow, I edited this question, so lets start from here.

```
;WITH CTE       
AS (SELECT *,                   
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBTYPE ORDER BY PRICE) AS RN,                    
COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBTYPE) AS Cnt             
FROM    all_resale)    
SELECT *    
FROM   CTE    
WHERE (CASE WHEN Cnt > 1 THEN 100.0 * (RN -1)/(Cnt -1) END) BETWEEN 1 AND 99
```

I'm not sure this is what I need to do. I don't know how many rows will be removed off the ends.

Comment: When you say "Remove" do you mean filter, or delete?

Comment: ALso 'Top 1% of sorted PRICE' is ambiguous - do you want to reduce the number of records by 1% ?

Comment: Filter. I would like it to remain in the data set, but not show up in this query. I'm trying to do some outlier control, but also can go back and do the process again with outliers. On the other hand, if the output was put into a new table, then it could be deleted completely in the new table.

Comment: Without example data and desired results this question has a certain amount of ambiguity. If a subtype has just 3 rows with prices `1,2,3` then do you want both outliers to be excluded? Given that is `67%` of the dataset not just entirely within the top and bottom `1%` And what about rows tied with the same value as excluded rows? Using some combination of `ROW_NUMBER`/`RANK` and `COUNT` should do it whatever though.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I've rephrased the question- hopefully this will explain better what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm none the wiser after the rephrasing. Example data and desired results will probably help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't specify exactly how you define the 1 percent and how ties should be handled.

One way is below

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBTYPE ORDER BY PRICE) AS RN,
                COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBTYPE) AS Cnt
         FROM    all_resale)
SELECT *
FROM   CTE
WHERE (CASE WHEN Cnt > 1 THEN 100.0 * (RN -1)/(Cnt -1) END) BETWEEN 1 AND 99
```

That assumes the highest price item is `100%`, the lowest price one `0%` and all others scaled evenly between taking no account of ties. If you need to take account of ties look into `RANK` rather than `ROW_NUMBER`

NB: If all of the subtypes have a relatively large amount of rows you could use [`NTILE(100)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx) instead but it does not distribute between buckets well if the number of rows is small relative to number of buckets.